# Matlab plotting a value which is referenced by another 2 values

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

In every iteration I get these values. For instance;

a is 2, b is 3, gg(a,b) is 70

a is 2, b is 4, gg(a,b) is 72

a is 2, b is 5, gg(a,b) is 76

I want to plot these in a one plot like 'a' in the x axes, 'b' in the y axes and gg(a,b) is the value which is referenced by a and b. I also want to show gg(a,b) values in a colormap. I tried but not achieved yet. Could you help please?
Here is what I've tried. I don't want 3d but don't know how to plot. Lets say gg is a matrix includes 20 columns and 5 rows.

```
gg=rand(5,20);
   for a=1:5
    for b=1:20
      hold on
      scatter3(gg(a,b),a,b)
      xlabel('gg(a,b)'), ylabel('a'), zlabel('b')
      colormap(jet)
      view(3)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so we can help point out what you were doing wrong.

Comment: I added the code. @tmpearce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a (simpler) code for both:

```
gg = rand(5,20);
[a,b] = ndgrid(1:5,1:20);
figure
scatter(a(:),b(:),[],gg(:))
colormap(jet)
xlim([0 6])
xlabel('a')
ylabel('b')
colorbar
figure
colormap(jet)
imagesc(1:5,1:20,gg.')
xlabel('a')
ylabel('b')
axis xy
colorbar
```

which creates:

[image: scatter]
[image: colormap]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not I want. I want that gg(a,b) values are seen from the graph. For ex; I don't see what gg(1,2) is in the graph. My all gg(a,b) values are between 0 and 1 in this example. I want to  show gg(a,b) values with colors. Also, I want to put a colorbar so I can understand that gg(a,b)'s  values acoording to the color.

Comment: If `a` is x, and `b` is y, they define a point in a 2-D scatter. Now you have another value `gg(a,b)` that you want to show in this point, you can do this by size or color (as in the example above) of the marker, I can't see how this is not done here (unless you want to _write_ the value instead of using the marker). If you want to show the colorbar, just add `colorbar` after you plot the data.

Comment: @DenizBaturay Right now my MATLAB is busy with a simulation, when it will finish (in ~36 hours), I'll update the answer with more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comment. I added colorbar and solved the problem. Thank you :)

Comment: @EBS In the second plot y axes start from 20 to 1 but it should be 1 to 20. Results are true when it is 1 to 20.

Comment: @EBS I wrote imagesc(1:20,1:10,gg) instead of yours. This gave the true result.

Comment: @DenizBaturay you right, but the more convenient way to solve this is to use `gg.'` in `imagesc`, and if you want it in the same directions as the scatter, add `axis xy` after it. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `gg=rand(5,20);`

Comment: No,it should be gg=rand(20,5).

Comment: Yeah but b has 5 for limit and you set it to 20 in your loop. So maybe switch b and a in your loops.